# Conky Variable Configuration Settings? (for graphs)

Tags: configuration, settings, conky

Is it possible to alternate configuration settings in a single conky coniguration file?

The problem I have is that I want visible scales on *some* graphs, but not all. This involves the `show_graph_scale`, which can be set to either 'yes' or 'no'.

Currently I run multiple instances of conky to achieve what I want, but conditional lines (e.g. `if_running`) cause them to overlap in some situations. Not exactly a perfect fix.

Comment: Can you provide conky version? `conky --version | head -n1`

Comment: Conky 1.9.0 compiled Wed Feb 19 18:44:57 UTC 2014 for Linux 3.2.0-37-generic (x86_64). 
Is it possible for newer versions? I looked over the documentation and didn't find anything.